# Can I use structural search in HTML files to find nested tags?

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I want to find and replace some child tags that are nested inside parent tag.
Here is my template:

```
<$tag$ $attribute$=$value$>
    <$childTag$ $childAttr$=$childValue$ />
<$tag$/>
```

I apply text filtering via regex to `$value$` and to `$childValue$`:

- `$value$` filter is `.*sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery--main.*`
- `$childValue$` filter is `sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide-img`

And this is a part of an HTML document where I want to find my `sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide-img` and replace it:

```
<div class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__main-gallery">
    <div class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__main-gallery-frame-wr swiper-container">
        <div class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__frame sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__main-gallery-frame swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__main-gallery-slide sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__main-gallery-slide--screenshot swiper-slide"
                 data-index="0" data-id="0">
                <div id="cmp-6" class="sm-ratio sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide-in">
                    <div class="sm-ratio__placeholder"></div>
                    <div class="sm-ratio__body">
                        <div class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide-cv"><img
                                class="sm-landing-appstore-app-1-gallery__slide-img"
                                src="img/Fitness%20Buddy/1.jpg" alt="EasyFitness gallery 1" data-number-image="1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the syntax of my search template is incorrect.
Is finding of nested tags even possible with IntelliJ structural search?

Comment: Please vote for the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183301

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, I've added my voice.